# pandas create a new column by checking a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 4 columns A,B,C,D and a List.i need to create columns using B,C,D columns and list as shown in the output section below.

```
hier_List= [[pages2 , book1  , paper3] , [pen1 , rifle2 , ink3] , [words1 ,book2, ink3]]
```

The column has to be created using the above lists.

dataframe:

```
A      B       C        D      
C_1     1971   book1    nan    
C_1     1971   pages2   pages2  
C_1     1970   book1    nan     
C_1     1972   book1    nan    
C_1     1973   letters4 nan
```

output:

For every row , I should check whether the C column value is present in any of the sub-list in the hier_list.if it is present flag yes else no.

```
 A      B       C        D       is_present_any_list
C_1     1971   book1    nan        yes  
C_1     1971   pages2   pages2     yes 
C_1     1970   book1    nan        yes  
C_1     1972   book1    nan        yes  
C_1     1973   letters4 nan        no
```

I cant figure out how to do this,Please help me on this and let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and flatten nested list with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
df['is_present_any_list'] = np.where(df['C'].isin(np.concatenate(hier_List)), 'yes', 'no')
print (df)
     A     B         C       D is_present_any_list
0  C_1  1971     book1     NaN                 yes
1  C_1  1971    pages2  pages2                 yes
2  C_1  1970     book1     NaN                 yes
3  C_1  1972     book1     NaN                 yes
4  C_1  1973  letters4     NaN                  no
```